# Run command line with named arguments from another bash script

Tags: linux, bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I have one script that takes the name of argument and its value, like this:

```
script1.sh --netId netIdValue
```

However, I'd like to call this command multiple times in another script, for the different values of netId argument.
So, in script2.sh I want to read the values of netIdValue from the .txt file and then to call the same command, like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    netIdValue=$line
    ./script1.sh --netId $netIdValue
done < netNames.txt
```

But, this fails, and it seem the problem is that it does not take --netId properly.
How can I pass the argument name and its value in script2.sh?

Comment: Do you really have `IFS-` or is that a typo? You want `IFS=`

Comment: Does netNames.txt contain `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: (1) Run your script with `bash -x yourscript` and read the trace logs emitted (and [edit] them into the question). (2) Include the error message in your question; let us evaluate what it "seems". (3) Glenn's comment above is almost certainly your problem.

Comment: It won't help your problem here, btw, but `--netId "$netIdValue"` is how the above code should be quoted.

Comment: (also, why use a `line` variable instead of `read -r netIdValue` to put the value directly into the name you want?)

Comment: IFS- was a typo, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

My script1.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1" "$2" - "$#"
```

If your ID's are in a file one per line, do this:

```
% cat file
1
2
% cat file | \
    xargs -I {} ./script1.sh --netId {}
--netId 1 - 2
--netId 2 - 2
```

If your ID's are on one line separated by spaces, do this:

```
% cat file
1 2
% cat file | tr ' ' '\0' | \
    xargs -0 -I {} ./script1.sh --netId {}
--netId 1 - 2
--netId 2 - 2
```

For the separation, I'm using `tr` to translate the spaces to null (\0) and using `xargs -0` option to separate inputs by nulls.